What does it mean to take the "trace" of a function?
I am a university student preparing for a report on density functional theory (DFT). When reading a paper on the DFT for van der Waals forces$^\dagger$, I was led to an equation for the non-local correlation energy functional in terms of the Coulomb interaction potential and some dielectric function. The energy functional given in the paper is
$$ E^{\text{nl}}_{\text{c}} = \int^\infty_0 \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\pi} \operatorname{tr}\left[ 
\ln\left(1 - V\tilde{\chi}\right) - \ln\epsilon \right], $$
where $V = 1 / \vert \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}^\prime\vert$ is the Coulomb interaction, $\tilde{\chi}$ is the density response to a self-consistent potential, and $\epsilon$ is a dielectric function such that in a uniform system we have $ 1 - V\tilde{\chi} = \epsilon$.
What is the mathematical meaning of taking the trace of functions of position in the above equation, in the setting of density functional theory?
$^\dagger$: M. Dion, H. Rydberg, E. Schr"{o}der, D. C. Langreth, and B. I. Lundqvist (2004). Van der Waals Density Functional for General Geometries; https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.246401.

First of all, I think it is important to you to know that they cite this equation as being the equation 24 of a broken link reference, which is the paper

Langreth, D. C., Dion, M., Rydberg, H., Schröder, E., Hyldgaard, P., & Lundqvist, B. I. (2005). Van der Waals density functional theory with applications. International journal of quantum chemistry, 101(5), 599-610.

Now your questions:

What is the mathematical meaning of taking the trace of functions of position?

When we have a function of two positions, like $n(\vec r,\vec r')$, the trace can be defined as
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{tr}(n) = \int  n(\vec r,\vec r)\quad d^3\vec r
\end{equation}
I didn't entered in details in the reference above, but probably the meaning of this expression should be explained there. You can also check in M Dion PhD Thesis

Dion, M. (2004). van der Waals forces in density functional theory. Rutgers The State University of New Jersey, School of Graduate Studies.


I think this is it. Also, the link in the paper is indeed broken as I remember, but the paper itself is still available.
